# Keeping dbcontext small

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dbcontext

Asp.Net Core 2 Web Api:

I was researching the other day and thought I saw a way to have a dbset in the dbcontext reference/target multiple models.

I'm not talking about Bounded Contexts.  At least I don't think I am.

I will have one project, but will utilize feature folder structure.

I have searched for hours today trying to find this information.  I don't really know what it's called, so my Google searches are not coming up with any relevant info.

My goal is to keep the dbcontext as small as possible versus having a dbset for each model.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Thanks,

John